# popup window dismiss android

Tags: android

I am using popup window and it is working good. There is list view in pop window and i am using it as `pw.showAsDropDown(anchorView);`

Where pw is PopupWindow and anchorView is the view, pop up will come underneath like a menu.

Now the strange problem is, i am not getting my suitable place/view, by pressing the place/view i can dismiss the pop up window.

`pw.setOutsideTouchable(true)` only works when `pw.setFocusable(false)`, but in this case list view unable to listen onItemClickListener on item list.
Even back key doesn't listen when pop up window is visible.

Can any body please help me out?